# Drop a database if there is no table in it

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a MySQL command can do something like:

> If there is nothing in a database, drop it. If there is any tables in it, do nothing.

Such as:

```
drop database if exists foobar
```

But:

```
drop database if empty foobar
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You could easily write a stored procedure that does this by querying `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`.

Comment: You have to write a stored procedure, normal drop database is not sufficient in this case ..

Comment: @Barmar Seems like that is. I'm new to SQL, is there any document or examples?

Comment: @KevinGuan just look at `select * from information_schema.tables` the info you see should give you an idea of what you need to do. You could get a count of tables and if its 0 then drop the database.

Comment: @JChao Wow, `select * from information_schema.tables` gives me 152 rows. Which one is that I'm looking for?

Comment: You want `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = "foobar";`. If this is 0, the database is empty. Then you can drop the database.

Comment: See the documentation on using prepared statements in stored procedures. It's on my mysql web site.

Comment: Here's the [Information Schema Tables Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tables-table.html)

Comment: And here's the documentation on [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)

Comment: Ah, thanks all. I understand how can I do this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this will help others as well. I just created a procedure for my own purpose after reading your question and commentators' comments.

```
use mysql;

-- switch to a different delimiter
delimiter $$

create procedure drop_empty_databases()
begin

    declare table_schema varchar(200); -- will hold schema obtained from query
    declare schema_end int default 0;  -- temp variable that's set to 1 when reading of all schema is done

    -- cursor that lists all schemas with no tables
    declare cur cursor for 
        select s.schema_name
        from information_schema.schemata s
        left join information_schema.tables t on t.table_schema = s.schema_name
        group by s.schema_name
        having count(t.table_name) = 0;

    -- set schema_end to 1 when we run out of schemas while looping
    declare continue handler for not found set schema_end = 1;

    open cur;
    looper: loop
        fetch cur into table_schema;
        if schema_end = 1 then
            leave looper;
        end if;

        set @sql = concat('drop database ', table_schema);
        prepare stmt from @sql;
        execute stmt;
    end loop;
    close cur;

end
$$

-- switch back to semi-colon delimiter
delimiter ;
```

Usage:

```
use mysql;
create database test123;
call drop_empty_databases();  -- test123 database should be gone after running this
```

Please test this on a **non**-production server and confirm that it does what you want it to do.

Comment: Interesting :) I've test this on my own computer and it works fine. Is there any way to select the database that I want to drop instead of all of the databases?

Comment: Yes. Absolutely. Create a parameter for the procedure called p_schema_name. Add a where clause before group by: where s.schema_name = p_schema_name. Call procname('test111') to drop test111 if it has no tables

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful :P

Answer (score 2):

As Barmar said you can use `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` with stored procedure.

Here is my small effort:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE spDropDB_IF_Empty()
BEGIN

IF (SELECT COUNT(table_name) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables
    WHERE Table_Schema = 'mariadb')= 0 THEN

    DROP DATABASE mariadb;

ELSE
    SELECT 'There are tables in the mariaDB';
END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Call SP:

```
CALL spDropDB_IF_Empty()
```

Comment: Well, since I don't know more about SQL, but seems like this doesn't work on my mariadb. It says `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT('There are tables in the test DB')' at line 1
`.

Comment: Now it doesn't raise an error, but seems still doesn't work. What does `(SELECT COUNT(table_name) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables
    WHERE Table_Schema = 'mariadb')` do?

Comment: @KevinGuan, That statement will count the number of tables in the database (mariadb). I have added it into the condition to check if there are tables then it should not drop the database. If it is equal to `= 0` then database has to drop.

Comment: @KevinGuan, Happy to help :)